# How to query dbpedia by property type value,

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am trying to write a SPARQL query to retrieve all pages that are linked to neighborhoods on Wikipedia. An example is **http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Carter_Crest,_Edmonton**. The property type is **http://dbpedia.org/property/settlementType** where **settlementType** should be **"neighbourhood"**, the other option is **template:infobox_settlement**.  So far, I've tried the following:

```sql
SELECT ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
WHERE {
  { <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> ?property ?hasValue }
  UNION
  { ?isValueOf ?property <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> }
}
```

```sql
SELECT ?class ?label
WHERE {
  ?class rdf:type owl:Place.
  ?class rdfs:label ?label. 
  FILTER(lang(?label) = "Neighbourhood")
}
```

Comment: `FILTER(lang(?label) = "Neighbourhood"` "Neighborhood" is not a language tag.  The **lang** function returns the language of a literal.  E.g., `lang("Joshua Taylor"@en)` returns `"en"`.

Comment: you can use `FILTER contains(str(?label), 'Neighbourhood')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement>` is the IRI of the *type* `Settlement`. Any particular settlement, such as Carter Crest, Edmonton, is an *instance* of that *type*.

By writing

```
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> ?property ?hasValue
```

you look for properties that are linked to the *type* `Settlement`, rather than to any instances of it. What you are looking for is any property that is linked to an arbitrary object of type `Settlement`:

```
?someObject ?property ?hasValue.
?someObject a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement>.
```

In your second query, what you are currently retrieving is any instance of type `owl:Place`, whose textual description equals `Neighbourhood` (which sounds like a type again, rather than a specific thing).

However, you probably want to retrieve an instance whose *type*'s label equals `Neighbourhood`. (And actually, you probably don't actually *want* to do that, either; that would be wild guessing that the type labeled `Neighbourhood` is what you are looking for. If you know the concrete type IRI, search for that as above.)

Comment: Thank you - so as I am looking for all neighbourhoods in wikipedia, I can then run the following... and take distinct entries from that correct? dbpedia live seems to have a limit of 2000 results, do you by any chance know of a way to solve that? SELECT ?someObject ?property ?hasValue ?isValueOf
WHERE {
   ?someObject ?property ?hasValue.
?someObject a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement>. }

Comment: @user3068287: Yes, without the semicolon, that should give you the results for properties in one of the directions. You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct entries. Also, you can paginate over the results with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to circumvent any restrictions on result rows retrieved with one query.

Comment: Sorry to bother again - but what if you are looking for a use of a property? Like to find things of a certain template? SELECT ?name ?member_Of ?country ?lat ?lng ?link
WHERE {
?x dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate "dbpedia:Template:Infobox_settlement" .
?x a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> .
?x foaf:name ?name .
?x dbpedia-owl:isPartOf ?member_Of.
?x dbpedia-owl:country ?country.
?x geo:lat ?lat .
?x geo:long ?lng .
?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?link .
}
LIMIT 2500 OFFSET 0

Comment: @user3068287: Yes, looks about right. It's a bit difficult to read in the comment, though; if this is a new question, please create a new SO question. That makes the information also easier to find for future visitors with the same or similar problems.

Comment: Apologies, it is a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894575/dbpedia-sparql-by-page-template