# DBpedia Sparql by page template

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to run a query on dbpedia using SPARQL syntax, to look for all pages of a certain template. Doesn't seem to be work, I am looking for all pages with dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate. Does anyone know how to correct this to properly look for templates?

```
SELECT ?name ?member_Of ?country ?lat ?lng ?link
WHERE {
?x dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate "dbpedia:Template:Infobox_settlement" .
?x a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> .
?x foaf:name ?name .
?x dbpedia-owl:isPartOf ?member_Of.
?x dbpedia-owl:country ?country.
?x geo:lat ?lat .
?x geo:long ?lng .
?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?link .
}
LIMIT 2500 OFFSET 0
```

I've also attempted to run it just by the dbprop to no avail.

```
SELECT * WHERE {  ?page dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_settlement> .  ?page dbpedia:name ?name .}
```

If anyone is trying to do a similar thing, it is also possible via the wiki api, where you can pagananate over all results. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=embeddedin&eititle=Template:Infobox_settlement

Comment: Try removing parts of the query patterns until you do get output.  Then you can identify which part is causing the lack of matches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax for Sparql query for pages with specific infobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812489/syntax-for-sparql-query-for-pages-with-specific-infobox);  it doesn't appear that DBpedia actually makes this information available through the endpoint.  That's the main problem here, in addition to the syntactic problems in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems: (i) you need to use IRIs in places, and not strings; and (ii) you need to use properties that DBpedia uses.

### Use IRIs

In

```
?x a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Settlement> .
```

and

```
?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?link .
```

you've demonstrated that you know that URIs need to be written in full with `<` and `>`, or abbreviated with a prefix.  However,

```
?x dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate "dbpedia:Template:Infobox_settlement" .
```

certainly isn't going to work.  It's legal SPARQL, because a string can be the object of a triple, but you almost certainly want an IRI.

### Use DBpedia's vocabulary

A query with **dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate** like this returns no results:

```
select distinct ?template where {
 [] dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate ?template
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Ftemplate%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%5B%5D%20dbpprop%3AwikiPageUsesTemplate%20%3Ftemplate%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

That's easy enough to check, and quickly confirms that there's no data that can *possibly* match your query.  Where did you find this property?  Have you seen it used somewhere?  I'm not confident that you can query DBpedia based on infobox templates.  DBpedia is not the same as Wikipedia, and even if the Wikipedia API supports it, it doesn't mean that DBpedia has a counterpart.  There *is* a note on [DBpedia Data Set Properties](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets/Properties) that says:

> http://xx.dbpedia.org/property/wikiPageUsesTemplate (will be changed to http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageUsesTemplate)

but that latter property doesn't seem to be in use on the endpoints either. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23834261/1281433) to [Syntax for Sparql query for pages with specific infobox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23812489/1281433) for more details.